# Where to locate string to change download link image/text in mb.miniaudioplayer WP plugin

Tags: wordpress, html

I want to trial the mb.miniaudioplayer, to offer free downloads from my Wordpress site. The download link for mb.miniaudioplayer shows as a `d`. How can I change this either to text `download` or an arrow button? I cannot find the relevant plugin file/string. Unfortunately, I get no response via the Wordpress plugin support.

The page is http://www.jamesclifford.at/mb-minaudio-try/. I've tried "string locator" in my WP site with various string names but nothing shows.